# Automatically Reflect Added Data to Table in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-tables

I have an "Add Data" pop up and it's saving properly to the database. I want it to automatically fetch the data from the database and retrieved the data back to the table in the user interface as I clicked the "Save" button. But the data is not showing automatically on the table, I still have to refresh my page to have it loaded. I think this has something to do with the state or hooks, but I don't understand how they really work. Can someone help me determine what seems to be the problem in here? Thanks.

This is the js file for Add Data (imports excluded):

```
export default class AddDataPopup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.drpCategorySelected = this.props.selectedHeader.categoryId;
        this.txtName = "";
        this.txtDescription = "";

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.resetField(nextProps.selectedHeader);

    }

    getDrpCategory = (value) => {
        this.drpCategorySelected = value;
        this.defineDialog();
    }

    
    getTxtName = (event) => {
        this.txtName = event.target.value
    }

    getTxtDescription = (event) => {
        this.txtDescription = event.target.value
    }


    resetField = (selectedHeader) => {
        this.drpCategorySelected = selectedHeader.categoryId;
        this.txtName = "";
        this.txtDescription = "";
        this.refs.dialog.hide();
    }



    //Save button
    addData = () => {
        var errorMessage = "";


        if (this.drpCategorySelected === '' || this.drpCategorySelected === undefined || this.drpCategorySelected === null || this.drpCategorySelected.length === 0) {
            errorMessage = "Please select Category<\n>";
        }
        if (this.txtName.trim() === "" || this.txtName === null || this.txtName === undefined) {
            errorMessage += "Please enter Name<\n>";
        } else if (this.txtName.trim().length > 100) {
            errorMessage += "Name exceeded character limit<\n>";
        }
        if (this.txtDescription.trim() === "" || this.txtDescription === null || this.txtDescription === undefined) {
            errorMessage += "Please enter Description<\n>";
        } else if (this.txtDescription.trim().length > 1000) {
            errorMessage += "Description exceeded character limit<\n>";
        }

        if (errorMessage.length > 0) {

            errorMessage = errorMessage.split('<\n>').map((item, key) => {
                return <span key={key}>{item}<br /></span>;
            });
            this.props.showAlert("error", errorMessage);
            this.refs.dialog.show();
            return;
        }



        this.postCreateNewData();

    }

    //This function calls data save api, and validate if input already exist, if not then save data

    postCreateNewData() {
        var id_ = Utilities.getCurrentID();
        var token_ = Utilities.getToken();
        var url_ = Utilities.getApiHttps();

        var data = {
            "categoryId": this.drpCategorySelected,
            "newName": this.txtName.trim(),
            "newDescription": this.txtDescription.trim()
        }


        return fetch(url_ + '<path>' + data, {

            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                if (responseJson.status === "Success") {
                    this.props.showAlert("success", "Successfully created new data");
                    this.props.refreshParameterList(true);
                    this.props.getData();
                    this.resetField(this.props.selectedHeader);
                } else if (responseJson.status === "DATA EXISTS") {
                    this.props.showAlert("error", "Data already exists for selected heading");
                    this.defineDialog();
                    this.refs.dialog.show();
                }

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("An error occurred fetching data.");
            });
    }

    defineDialog = () => {

        Dialog.setOptions({
            defaultCancelLabel: 'Cancel'
        });
        this.refs.dialog.show({
            title: <p className="modal-title-margin">
                Add Data
                    <Glyphicon glyph='remove'
                    className='close'
                    onClick={() => this.resetField(this.props.selectedHeader)}
                />
            </p>,
            body: (
                <div className="modal-body-margin">
                    <Col xs={12} md={12}>

                        <CategoryDropdown
                            data1={this.getDrpCategory}
                            initialData={this.drpCategorySelected}
                            userId={this.props.user_id}
                            userRole={this.props.role_id}
                        />

                            <FormGroup>
                            <Label>Name</Label>
                                <FormControl
                                    type="text"
                                    defaultValue={this.txtName}
                                    onChange={this.getTxtName}
                                    placeholder="Enter Name"
                                />
                            </FormGroup>

                            <div><Label>Description</Label></div>
                            <textarea
                                placeholder="Enter Description"
                                onChange={this.getTxtDescription}>
                            </textarea>
                        </Col>

                    </Col>
                </div>
            ),
            bsSize: 'medium',
            actions: [
                Dialog.CancelAction(() => this.resetField(this.props.selectedHeader)),
                Dialog.Action(
                    <span>Save</span>,
                    this.addData,
                    'btn btn-success'
                )
            ],
            onHide: (() => this.resetField(this.props.selectedHeader))
        });
    }

    openPopup = () => {
        this.resetField(this.props.selectedHeader);
        this.defineDialog();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <row>
                <button onClick={this.openPopup}>+ Add New Data</button>
                <Dialog ref='dialog' />
            </row>
        );
    }
```

And here's the js file for the landing page of the data or the table (imports also excluded):

```
export default class DataMain extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            nameList: [],
            categoryList: {},
            descriptionList = {}
        }

        this.categoryList = {};
        this.descriptionList = {};
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {


        //Should refresh Data List
        if (!this.props.shouldRefreshDataList && nextProps.shouldRefreshDataList) {
            this.getData();
            this.props.refreshDataList(false);
        }
        this.setDropdownFilters();
    }

    setDropdownFilters = () => {
        if (this.props.selectedHeader.name === undefined) {
            this.refs.drpCategory.applyFilter('');
            return;
        }
        this.refs.drpCategory.applyFilter(this.props.selectedHeader.categoryName);


    }


    //This function calls Data list api, and fill dataList state
    getData = () => {
        var id_ = Utilities.getCurrenID();
        var token_ = Utilities.getToken();
        var url_ = Utilities.getApiHttps();

        return fetch(url_ + '<path>' + this.props.user_id, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_,
                'pragma': 'no-cache',
                'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.nameList = {};
                this.categoryList = {};
                this.descriptionList = {};
                

                for (var x = 0; x < responseJson.length; x++) {

                    this.categoryList[responseJson[x].categoryName] = responseJson[x].categoryName;
                    this.descriptionList[responseJson[x].descriptionName] = responseJson[x].description;
                    
                }

                this.categoryList = sortObject(this.categoryList);
                this.descriptionList = sortObject(this.descriptionList);

                this.setState({
                    nameList: responseJson, categoryList: this.categoryList,
                    descriptionList: this.descriptionList
                });

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("An error occured fetching data.");
            });
    }


    }

    render() {


        return (
            <Col xs={12} md={12}>

                <br />
                <AddDataPopup
                    getData={this.getData}
                    refreshParameterList={this.props.refreshParameterList}
                    showAlert={this.showAlert}
                    user_id={this.props.user_id}
                    role_id={this.props.role_id}
                    selectedHeader={this.props.selectedHeader}
                />

                <BootstrapTable
                    data={this.state.dataList}
                    striped={true}
                    hover={true}
                    scrollTop={'Bottom'}
                    pagination={true}
                >
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                        ref="drpCategory"
                        dataField='categoryName'
                        tdStyle={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }}
                        width='100'
                        filter={{ type: 'SelectFilter', options: this.state.categoryList, condition: 'eq' }}
                    >
                        Category
                    </TableHeaderColumn>

                    <TableHeaderColumn
                        dataField='Name'
                        dataSort={true}
                        tdStyle={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }}
                        filter={{ type: 'TextFilter' }}
                        width='100'
                    >
                        Name
                    </TableHeaderColumn>

                    <TableHeaderColumn
                        dataField='description'
                        dataSort={true}
                        tdStyle={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }}
                        width='100'
                    >
                        Description
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
    
            </BootstrapTable>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When your post method is successful add the data in dataList no need to apply get method to fetch data because you already have data(which you are sending in post method).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand clearly. Please explain further. I would also like to fetch those data that I have added before, not just the recently added data. @Abhi

Comment: when your page loads first time, I think you will be fetching all rows from DB. So when you add new row by post method you just append it at top of your existing data(fetched when page first time load).When you will visit this page again, You will get all the data. I hope you understand my point

Comment: check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/dynamic-react-table-with-add-and-delete-row-in-sharepoint-framework-spfx2